# How come I can't include other URLs.py into my Django?

Tags: python, django, templates, url, notifications

I have a urls.py. One of them says this line:

```
(r'^notification/?$',include("notification.urls")),
```

I'm supposed to do that because I installed "django_notification" (and added "notification") to INSTALLED_APPs.

Great! going to /notification/ works! This is the urls.py in the notification module:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from notification.views import notices, mark_all_seen, feed_for_user, single, notice_settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', notices, name="notification_notices"),
    url(r'^settings/$', notice_settings, name="notification_notice_settings"),
    url(r'^(\d+)/$', single, name="notification_notice"),
    url(r'^feed/$', feed_for_user, name="notification_feed_for_user"),
    url(r'^mark_all_seen/$', mark_all_seen, name="notification_mark_all_seen"),
)
```

**However, only /notification works and it displays the word "notice" when I hit that url. Nothing else works. /settings, /feed. None of that work.  I get a 404 error that Django tried all the URLs in order.**

Perhaps it's because of the "notification_notice" thing??

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation, you'll see that the include will remove the part that matches, so you'd have to go to /notification/settings, and /notification/feed

Comment: Yes, I go to mydomain.com/notifications/ettings .  But that doesn't work.  However, I've tried all sorts of things in my urls and it doesn't work.

Comment: @TIMEX: "it doesn't work" is vague and hard to interpret.  Can you be more precise on what works and what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

I removed the `?$` at the end of the url match.